# scroll-behaviour: smooth, not working when element is removed

Tags: javascript, css

I have a small table made out of divs with an 'add new' button to add a new line and an x button on each line to remove the line. The table has a max-height and once this is reached scrolls to the bottom when a new line is added. I have set scroll-behaviour to smooth in the css so that once the tables max height has been reached adding and taking away lines can be seen by the user. This is working well if a new line is added, but doesn't work at all when a line from the bottom is removed. I have tried to add the smallest amount of code to replicate the problem.

I have tried using jquery animate and intervals, but can't get the scroll to show when a line is removed.

```js
//ADD NEW LINE//

function addNewLine() {
  var productsLinesBox = document.getElementsByClassName("products-lines-box");
  var productItemLine = document.createElement("div");
  productItemLine.classList.add("product-item-line");
  productsLinesBox[0].appendChild(productItemLine);
  var productItemSKU = document.createElement("div");
  var spn = document.createElement("span");
  productItemSKU.classList.add("product-item", "sku");
  productItemLine.appendChild(productItemSKU);
  productItemSKU.appendChild(spn);
  var productItemName = document.createElement("div");
  var spn1 = document.createElement("span");
  productItemName.classList.add("product-item", "name");
  productItemLine.appendChild(productItemName);
  productItemName.appendChild(spn1);
  var productItemQty = document.createElement("div");
  var spn2 = document.createElement("span");
  productItemQty.classList.add("product-item", "qty");
  productItemLine.appendChild(productItemQty);
  productItemQty.appendChild(spn2);
  var productItemPrice = document.createElement("div");
  var spn3 = document.createElement("span");
  productItemPrice.classList.add("product-item", "price");
  productItemLine.appendChild(productItemPrice);
  productItemPrice.appendChild(spn3);
  var productItemDelete = document.createElement("div");
  var spn4 = document.createElement("span");
  productItemDelete.classList.add("product-item", "delete");
  spn4.innerHTML = "x";
  spn4.onclick = function() {
    deleteThis(this.parentNode.parentNode);
  }
  productItemLine.appendChild(productItemDelete);
  productItemDelete.appendChild(spn4);

  productsLinesBox[0].scrollTop = productsLinesBox[0].scrollHeight;
}


//DELETE LINE//

function deleteThis(productLine) {
  productLine.parentNode.removeChild(productLine);
}
```

```css
.products-lines-box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 14px;
  max-height: 90px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.products-lines-box::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.product-item-line {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 34px;
}

.product-item {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 34px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.product-item.sku {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.product-item.delete {
  width: 20px;
}

.product-item.delete span {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.new-line-box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(55% - 14px);
  margin: 6px 0 0 14px;
}

.new-line-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 4.5px 8px 4.5px 8px;
  color: black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 11.5px;
  border: 0.5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="products-lines-box">
  <div class="product-item-line">
    <div class="product-item sku">
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="product-item delete">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="new-line-box">
  <button type="button" id="newLineBtn" class="new-line-btn" onclick="addNewLine()">
      <span>Add new line</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else looking for a solution. Wouter's answer works perfectly. I have added extra stages to give extra smoothness.

```
.products-lines-box.deleting1::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 36px;
  clear: both;
}
.products-lines-box.deleting2::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
  clear: both;
}
.products-lines-box.deleting3::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 12px;
  clear: both;
}
```

```
    function deleteThis(productLine) {
        var productsLinesBox = document.getElementsByClassName("products-lines-box")[0];
        productsLinesBox.classList.add('deleting1');
        productsLinesBox.removeChild(productLine);
        productsLinesBox.scrollTop = productsLinesBox.children.length * 36 - 90;
        setTimeout(function () {
            productsLinesBox.classList.replace('deleting1', 'deleting2')
        }, 200)
        setTimeout(function () {
            productsLinesBox.classList.replace('deleting2', 'deleting3')
        }, 250)
        setTimeout(function () {
            productsLinesBox.classList.remove('deleting3')
        }, 300)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The element is not scrolling smoothly when you delete an element in it, because an element cannot scroll below its bottom. i.e. `scrollTop` can never be greater than `(scrollHeight - offsetHeight)`.
When adding an item to the list, the `scrollHeight` of the list increases and hence, the element can scroll smoothly to its new position.
To make the element scroll smoothly when deleting a line, you have to temporarily increase the height of the element, scroll up the height of a line, and then decrease the height of the element. This can be accomplished like this: (I've tried to reuse as much of your code as possible)

```js
//ADD NEW LINE//

var productLinesBox = document.getElementsByClassName("products-lines-box")[0];

function addNewLine() {
  var productItemLine = document.createElement("div");
  productItemLine.classList.add("product-item-line");
  productLinesBox.appendChild(productItemLine);
  var productItemSKU = document.createElement("div");
  var spn = document.createElement("span");
  productItemSKU.classList.add("product-item", "sku");
  productItemLine.appendChild(productItemSKU);
  productItemSKU.appendChild(spn);
  var productItemName = document.createElement("div");
  var spn1 = document.createElement("span");
  productItemName.classList.add("product-item", "name");
  productItemLine.appendChild(productItemName);
  productItemName.appendChild(spn1);
  var productItemQty = document.createElement("div");
  var spn2 = document.createElement("span");
  productItemQty.classList.add("product-item", "qty");
  productItemLine.appendChild(productItemQty);
  productItemQty.appendChild(spn2);
  var productItemPrice = document.createElement("div");
  var spn3 = document.createElement("span");
  productItemPrice.classList.add("product-item", "price");
  productItemLine.appendChild(productItemPrice);
  productItemPrice.appendChild(spn3);
  var productItemDelete = document.createElement("div");
  var spn4 = document.createElement("span");
  productItemDelete.classList.add("product-item", "delete");
  spn4.innerHTML = "x";
  spn4.onclick = function() {
    deleteThis(this.parentNode.parentNode);
  }
  productItemLine.appendChild(productItemDelete);
  productItemDelete.appendChild(spn4);

  productLinesBox.scrollTop = productLinesBox.scrollHeight;
}


//DELETE LINE//

function deleteThis(productLine) {
  productLinesBox.classList.add('deleting');
  productLinesBox.removeChild(productLine);
  productLinesBox.scrollTop = productLinesBox.children.length * 36 - 90;
  setTimeout(function () {
     productLinesBox.classList.remove('deleting')
  }, 500)
}
```

```css
.products-lines-box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 14px;
  max-height: 90px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.products-lines-box.deleting::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 36px;
  clear: both;
}

.products-lines-box::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.product-item-line {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 34px;
}

.product-item {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 34px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.product-item.sku {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.product-item.delete {
  width: 20px;
}

.product-item.delete span {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.new-line-box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(55% - 14px);
  margin: 6px 0 0 14px;
}

.new-line-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 4.5px 8px 4.5px 8px;
  color: black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 11.5px;
  border: 0.5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="products-lines-box">
  <div class="product-item-line">
    <div class="product-item sku">
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="product-item delete">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="new-line-box">
  <button type="button" id="newLineBtn" class="new-line-btn" onclick="addNewLine()">
      <span>Add new line</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Wouter, this works brilliantly. I have adapted your code with a couple of extra deleting class and three interval stages to add smoothness.